# Storing file location of DICOM images in SQL database

Tags: sql, database

I want to store `DICOM` images in a directory somewhere, create a database of specific parameters relating to the `DICOM` images and add the relative location of the `DICOM` files to the database.

How do I go about doing this in Design view instead of coding explicitly? (I'm relatively new to database / SQL that sort of thing which is why I'd prefer doing it in design view at least at first).

I have searched for questions related to this topic, however all I came up with was posts debating whether it was better to store the images themselves in the database or a pointer to the location.

Can somebody tell me exactly how to go about doing it instead of the pros and cons of the different methods?

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the developers of an imaging platform called [XNAT](http://www.xnat.org/).  Our system has the features you describe (among others), and our implementation uses the "pointer" approach.  That decision has worked out well for us and we've no plans to change it.

Especially if you're new to SQL, I would recommend the pointer approach -- the storage/retrieval will be simpler, since you'll be storing a string rather than a (potentially large) image.

You mention wanting to do things in Design view - are you working in a .NET/Visual Studio environment?  If so, [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021.aspx) should be of use to you.  Or, if you'd like Design view to generate some of the ADO.NET code for you, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx) has tips for creating DataSets in the GUI.

Of course, I'd also encourage you to give [XNAT](http://www.xnat.org/) a look.  Our platform is Java-based, not .NET, but it's open-source and freely available.  It speaks DICOM out-of-the-box and can act as a C-STORE SCP (meaning you can send data to it directly from a scanner).

Comment: Yes, I'm working in .NET/VS. I'll look into ADO.NET, thanks Evan.

But XNAT would probably only serve to pull me into deeper waters since I'm not acquainted with Java.

Comment: Sure thing.  I've added another link in the answer that has some recipes for creating ADO.NET DataSets in the GUI.